# Retrieve value from linked data type

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub view_UCC_Breakdown()
dim zipCode as string
dim groupCode as string

startSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

If InStr(1, Cells(5, ActiveCell.Column()).Value, "Units") > 0 Then

    growthRate = Cells(316, ActiveCell.Column()).Value
    marketShare = Cells(319, (ActiveCell.Column() + 1)).Value
    
Else

    growthRate = Cells(316, (ActiveCell.Column() - 1)).Value
    marketShare = Cells(319, ActiveCell.Column()).Value
    
End If

zipCode = Range("E6").Value

end sub
```

I'm working on this code that needs to get some data on the sheet, in this case range E6 is a cell with a geography data type (has zip codes in there). For some reason it keeps storing the value of Zip Code as an error. I feel like this is because E6 is a linked data type. Any idea how to retrieve the value of the zip code?

Comment: Why don't you look at your formula in E6 - you don't show it here

Comment: Does E6 display a corerct value? If not then fix the issue there. If E6 is fine then try to declare zipCode as `Variant` and see what happens. There may be a type conversion issue.